# Rails - Setting a form textarea size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Im trying to resize a simple textarea in Rails and its having no effect. Other posts on Stackoverflow mention this solution

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>



    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :projectDetails,  placeholder: "Project Details..."  cols: "30", rows: "10" %>
      </div>
    </div>




<% end %>
```

When i use this it makes no difference. Is there something im missing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<%= f.text_area :projectDetails,  placeholder: "Project Details...", :hatch, size: "30x10" %>
```

Comment: Yeah ive tried that and it has no effect. its more the height i want as the width is set by the col-md-12 div.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= f.text_area :hatch, cols: "30", rows: "10" %>
<%= f.text_area :hatch, size: "30x10" %>
```

Comment: what does hatch mean?

Comment: Your code generate this html `<textarea cols="30" id="form_projectDetails" name="form[projectDetails]" placeholder="Project Details..." rows="10"></textarea>` please include your html

Comment: Ive added the whole lot now.